# Flutter BottomNavigationBarItem original color

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, flutter-bottomnavigation

When i'm using BottomNaviagtionBar with BottomNavigationBarItem the color of selected BottomNavigationBarItem is the color selectedItemColor but i wan't to use the original color, because my image has two different colors when I try to use transparent color my icon disappear

Thanks for your help

Comment: could you please add the full code you have done so far?

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to use the default color, then don't specify any values to selectedItemColor. If that doesn't work try finding a color that doesn't cause such a problem and use it. Here are all the colors flutter has, I am sure you will find the right one, just keep lookin'

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Colors-class.html

Comment: If you don't specify color flutter use the android primary color and I want to use the color in my image don't a color look like (My image have multi color)